# I am trying to get a view on top of a UITabBar where the tab bar is hidden once the view appears on it using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, hide, uitabbar

I am trying to add a view on top of UITabbar. Once the view appears ,I want the tab bar to hide itself.
Below I am attaching a view that I want to create (the bottom view that has buttons on it). I have a tab bar behind it and I want this view to appear once we click on the icon with three dots.
[This is the view that I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jurwy.png)

I added below code to present a view over tabbar but it is aligning to the centre and I am not aware how to bring it to the bottom. I tried using constraints but that didn't work.
Attaching the view i created in storyboard:
[I want to show this view on tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gfY3.png) Its a dummy view for now.

```
Code:
 func showViewOnEyeBtnPressed() {
        self.view.addSubview(showViewOnEyeBtn)
        showViewOnEyeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        showViewOnEyeBtn.alpha = 0
        showViewOnEyeBtn.center = self.view.center
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.showViewOnEyeBtn.alpha = 1
            self.showViewOnEyeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
```

Note: After trying suggestions from the comment my view looks like this: [View after adding suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFQ1K.png) I want that green view to occupy the tab bar view once it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that - you are calling this on `UIViewController.view` where your `UIViewController` is embedded inside the `UITabBarController`.

You should call following on `UITabBarController.view` instance like -

```
func showViewOnEyeBtnPressed() {
   guard let targetView = self.tabBarController?.view ?? self.view else { return }
   
   targetView.addSubview(showViewOnEyeBtn)
   showViewOnEyeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
   showViewOnEyeBtn.alpha = 0
   showViewOnEyeBtn.center = self.view.center
   
   self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true 
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
       self.showViewOnEyeBtn.alpha = 1
       self.showViewOnEyeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
   }, completion: { (_) in
       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
   })
}
```

Comment: Sure, I will try that out, but i still don't get that view to the bottom. Please could you help me fix that ? @Tarun Tyagi

Comment: As long as you add it to the correct view, in this case `UITabBarViewController.view`, you should be fine. Try hiding the `TabBar` first and then adding this view, check your constraints.

Comment: The tab bar is getting hidden but my view is still not appearing on it. I tried using constraints but it didn't work. @Tarun Tyagi

Comment: I have added an Image of how my view looks now , i want it to occupy the tab bar space after its hidden. @Tarun Tyagi. I added the same code you made changes in but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried using this suggestion [ newView.frame = tabBarController.tabBar.frame
tabBarController.view.addSubview(newView) ] from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821472/adding-custom-view-above-tab-bar-controller-navigation-controller , It took place of the tab bar but the view behind is blank. I want it to look as it is. Can you help @ Tarun Tyagi